# trying to read from a bat file but but it giving me an error

Tags: c#

I'm have 2 bat file one customer.bat and the other barista.bat, i can read from the customer.bat but i cant read from barista.bat and it giving me this error 
"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type                 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Customer]' to type     'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Barista]'.'
"

I'm have 2 bat file one customer.bat and the other barista.bat, i can read from the customer.bat but i cant read from barista.bat and it giving me this error 
"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Customer]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Barista]'.'"

It should work becouse it the some as the customer.bat but i dont know what going wronng

program.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{


    static int ShowMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Choose; ");
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.WriteLine("1. New Customer. ");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Login. ");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Quit.");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        return choice;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int choice = 0;
        do
        {
            choice = ShowMenu();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    AddCustomer();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Login();
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (choice != 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit ");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }



    private static void AddCustomer()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Customer c = new Customer();

        Console.Write("Name: ");
        c.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Surname: ");
        c.Surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("ID: ");
        c.ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Email Address: ");
        c.EmailAddress = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Home Address: ");
        c.HomeAddress = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Mobile Number: ");
        c.MobNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        c.Username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        c.Password = Console.ReadLine();
        //            Console.Write("Coffee Points: ");
        //            c.CoffeeP = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        ManagerOrder.Instance.AddCustomer(c);
        ManagerOrder.Instance.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void Login()
    {

        const string FILENAME_BARISTA = "barista.dat";
        const string FILENAME_CUSTOMER = "customer.dat";

        Console.Clear();
        Console.Write("Username: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();



        List<Customer> pCustomer = Customer.ReadData<Customer>(FILENAME_CUSTOMER);
        Customer.CustomerCreatedInstances = pCustomer;
        IEnumerable<Customer> cu = pCustomer.Where(customers => customers.Username == username & customers.Password == password);

        string validUsername;
        string validPassword;

        foreach (var c in pCustomer)
        {
            validUsername = c.Username;
            validPassword = c.Password;

            if (validUsername == username && validPassword == password)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer login");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Barista Login");

                List<Barista> myBarista = Barista.ReadData<Barista>(FILENAME_BARISTA);

                Barista.BaristaCreatedInstances = myBarista;

                IEnumerable<Barista> barist = myBarista.Where(barista => barista.Username == username & barista.Password == password);

                foreach (var ba in myBarista)
                {

                    validUsername = ba.Username;
                    validPassword = ba.Password;

                    if (validUsername == username && validPassword == password)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("barista Login");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("worng ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
}
```

Barista.cs

```
 public class Barista
{
    public static List<Barista> BaristaCreatedInstances;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public int MobNumber { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public Barista()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Surname = string.Empty;
        ID = 0;
        EmailAddress = string.Empty;
        HomeAddress = string.Empty;
        MobNumber = 0;
        Username = string.Empty;
        Password = string.Empty;
    }

    public Barista(string n, string s, int id, string ea, string ha, int mobn ,string user, string pass)
    {
        n = Name;
        s = Surname;
        id = ID;
        ea = EmailAddress;
        ha = HomeAddress;
        mobn = MobNumber;
        user = Username;
        pass = Password;
    }

    public static void WriteData(List<Barista> objectToSerialize, string FILENAME_BARISTSA)
    {
        Instance<Barista>.WriteData(objectToSerialize, FILENAME_BARISTSA);
    }

    public static List<Barista> ReadData<ba>(string FILENAME_BARISTA)
    {
        return Instance<Barista>.ReadData<Barista>(FILENAME_BARISTA);
    }
    //public Login(String username, string password)
    //{
    //    this.u = user1;
    //    this.p = pass1;
    //}


}
}
```

Instance.cs

```
public class Instance<T>
{
    static Stream stream;
    static IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static void WriteData(List<T> objectToSerialize, string FILENAME_CUSTOMER)
    {

        stream = new FileStream(FILENAME_CUSTOMER, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);


        formatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);

        Console.WriteLine("Write done");

        stream.Close();
    }

    //Stream file = File.Open("FILENAME_CUSTOMER" + Customer.CustomerCreatedInstances, FileMode.Open);
    //BinaryFormatter bfor = new BinaryFormatter();
    //Customer cust = (Customer)BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    //stream.Close()
    public static List<T> ReadData<T>(string filePath)
    {
        stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        Object deserializedObject = formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        Console.WriteLine("Read done");
        stream.Close();
        return (List<T>)deserializedObject;

    }




}
```

I expected to readfrom the file and the login will work but it giving me an error 
https://ibb.co/HdBbCLN

Comment: Can you please tell us which line the error is occurring on?

Comment: Looks like `FILENAME_BARISTA` actually contains serialized `Customer` object

Comment: I have uploaded an image with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the problem Opewix was right I was creating a customer object instead of a barista object

thanks